# Why I don't have the 'formatter' attribute in my Symfony2 Form?

Tags: symfony-2.1

I was wondering, since an update of Symfony2.1 (I can't target the commit though) why I no longer have the `"formatter"` attribute on my `jQueryDateType`

```
if ($form->getConfig()->hasAttribute('formatter'))
```

returns `false`

The whole class is here : https://gist.github.com/d3c74c12d60e20df84c3

Answer (score 0):

the getParent() function was missing and solved half of the problem.